# Is there a way to put negative sign before dollar sign

Tags: r

Is there a way to put negative sign before dollar sign, For example, below output is positive and the output is fine

```
paste0("$ ",formatC(2344, format="f", digits=2, big.mark=","))
[1] "$ 2,344.00"
```

But if the number is negative, dollar sign comes before that.

```
paste0("$ ",formatC(-2344, format="f", digits=2, big.mark=","))
[1] "$ -2,344.00"
```

expeted output

```
> paste0("$ ",formatC(-2344, format="f", digits=2, big.mark=","))
[1] "- $ 2,344.00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format_dollar <- function(x) {
ifelse(x<0, sprintf("-$%.2f", abs(x)), sprintf("$%.2f", x)) 
}

format_dollar(c(2344, -2344))

# [1] "$2344.00"  "-$2344.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably use `scales::dollar` ?

```
scales::dollar(2344)
#[1] "$2,344"

scales::dollar(-2344)
#[1] "-$2,344"
```

Look at their source code which is written in R by typing `scales::dollar` in the console. Probably, that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Great. Can we add a space here for ````- $2,344````

Comment: `scales::dollar(-2344, prefix = " $")`

Comment: Good answer for that specific currency (+1). Note, the help page of package version 1.1.1 says `dollar() and format_dollar() are retired; please use label_dollar() instead.`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifelse()`

```
x <- c(-2344, 2344)
paste0(ifelse(x < 0, "- ", ""), "$ ", formatC(abs(x), format="f", digits=2, big.mark=","))big.mark=","))
# [1] "- $ 2,344.00" "$ 2,344.00"
```

Comment: Use `trimws` to get rid of the leading white space

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Well spotted. I change the solution slightly to avoid it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub`:

```
x <- c(-2344, 2344)
sub("\\$ -", "- $", paste0("$ ",formatC(x, format="f", digits=2, big.mark=",")))
# [1] "- $2,344.00" "$ 2,344.00"
```